# OpenCV Edge Match

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am pretty new to opencv and I have read some tutorials and projects source code. It seems that people tend to do the object detection base on color.

I wonder if there is a way to do the object detection base on the curve of the edge.

For example, I have a known object whose edge is like A, and I have known that the edge of this object in different images is pretty similar but not the same, like B. Now consider B is in the Pic C, and my target is to find out the contour or edge of B in the C based on the searching for the similar shape of A in the C.

So is there any method of contour detection or edge detection based on the searching for the similar shape of an known shape.

[image: My Example Image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the default method in OpenCV is `matchShapes`; but I have used a generic method that works rather well.

- For each contour, take the centroid.
- Following the contour from the point highest above the centroid, take the distance to the centroid.
- Move a step along the contour (for example 1/100 of the length of the contour). The the distance again.
- After all the steps, you have a arrays of distances.
- Compare arrays, for example using Cosine similarity

You can make this method scale and rotation invariant.

- If you want to have *scale* invariance, normalize the array before comparison.
- If you want to have *rotation* invariance, you can shift the array and find the best match over the shifst

Comment: Can you please provide a sample code ? That would make it more simpler to understand